# Get custom category name from ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am having issues retrieving a custom category name. I already have its ID, which is coming to me from a custom field.
I don't know if it makes any difference, but I'm using Woocommerce.

I'm trying to do this:

```
<?php get_term_by( 'id', $my_custom_cat_id, 'product-cat') ?>
```

But I get an empty value back, even though I know the category ID is correct (I am using it as query args already)

Many thanks

Comment: That code should work. Please file an [edit] with how you retrieve the value from you custom field and how are you using the result from `get_term_by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the inline comments. Not tested. The following code will grab all the Custom Taxonomy Terms of Custom Taxonomy 'product-cat' and will show them one by one from the result array.

```
<?php
global $post;
$postID = $post->ID //get/put your post ID here
$getProductCat = get_the_terms( $postID, 'product-cat' ); //as it's returning an array
foreach ( $getProductCat as $productInfo ) {
    echo $productInfo->name;
}
```

Comment: I'd love to say this work, but as soon as $postID = $post->ID is into the page, the page stops rendering

Comment: How are you grabbing post_id? I just put that globally. Grab the post id from your context and pass there. I said there `get` or `put` - it your turn. I don't know where you are implementing th code. :)